# Can't get my router to forward ports to my raspberry pi web server

Tags: networking, nginx, port, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I am setting up a raspberry pi to use as a web server but I can't seem to get the port forwarding to work from my router to my pi. I have set my router to port all ports from 1 - 9999 just to see if it works but I can't ssh onto my pi using the public ip address only my local one works, and I am also unable to access my nginx web server on my pi. My pi and router both have a static ip address and I am defiantly forwarding to the correct ip on the raspberry pi. I have a d-link DSL2680 router and was wondering if anyone else has had the same problem or knows something that I might be missing. Thanks.

Comment: might be shot in the dark; but I know some ISP's block ports 1-1024. Open a port in a higher range and link to an internal port of choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most routers only trigger port forwarding if the connection is coming from the public interface. You'll need to try ssh'ing in from outside your network. Not just using the public IP address, but from a device that would need to enter your network via the public interface on your router.

Comment: Cheers mate exactly what I needed I can't believe that's all it was. Cheers.